# SQL - SUM, Distinct and TOP 4

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query for a table that I cant get to work.

Below are tables examples;

Table **Members**:

```
|ID|NAME|
|1 |John|
|2 |Joe |
|3 |Paul|
```

Table **Scores**:

```
|ID  |Score |                       
|1   | 25   |                       
|1   | 34   |                       
|2   | 54   |                       
|1   | 23   |                       
|3   | 43   |                     
|2   | 14   |                       
|1   | 23   |                       
|3   | 43   |                     
|3   | 14   |                                             
|3   | 43   |                     
|2   | 14   |                       
|1   | 23   |                       
|3   | 43   |                     
|3   | 14   |
```

I want to display the members name and then Sum there best 2 scores, and display it with largest SUM'd score first.

```
|Paul| 86 |
|Joe | 68 |
|John| 57 |
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: What does `TOP 4` have to do with this?

Comment: Show us the query you have so far.

Comment: Why John have 57, is this typo? it should 59 (25+34), not ?

Comment: Sorry Top 2 it should be.

Comment: My Query so far is;SELECT DISTINCT member.name, 
(SELECT SUM(Select TOP 2 scores.score) as 'Top 2')
FROM members 
INNER JOIN scores
ON members.id = scores.id 
Group by member.name, scores.score Order by scores.scores DESC

Comment: Its ms management studio.  This is just a tiny part of a c# project, c# is grand but I need this query for a report and SQL is not my strong point

Answer (score 5):

You can use `row_number` window function  for achieve TOP 2 scores per id, then sum it using `group by` and finally join  to MEMBERS table, something like:

```
select MEMBERS.name, tt.s from MEMBERS
inner join (
    select  ID, sum(Score) s from (
        select ID, Score, row_number() over(partition by ID order by Score desc) rn from SCORES
    ) t
    where rn <= 2
    group by id
)tt
on MEMBERS.id = tt.id
ORDER BY tt.s
```

Comment: Where would I add an ORDER BY score?

Comment: @Senna - Happy to help, you can add ORDER BY at the end, I edited answer,  please see it

Comment: You're a Star Oto, i needed the tt.score, I just through I had the order by in the wrong place. I really should learn SQL but I never normally need anything more complicated than a basic query.  Thanks Again

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `group by` clause and a subselect

```
SELECT    M.NAME
          ,(SELECT SUM(S2.SCORE) 
           FROM   (SELECT TOP 2 S1.Score FROM SCORES S1
                   WHERE S1.ID = S.ID
                   ORDER BY S1.Score DESC) AS S2
           ) AS Two_Highest_Scores
FROM      SCORES S
LEFT JOIN MEMBERS M
       ON M.ID = S.ID
GROUP BY  M.ID
          ,M.NAME
```

Can you test that out ?

Comment: Thanks, tried this and it displays the sum of the two lowest scores, not too sure why?

Comment: Oh, it has to be ordered in DESC mode, I'll change it

Comment: Thanks Luis, you are a great help and fixed my silly issue in no time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query (SQL Server 2012+ needed)

```
SELECT name, best_score
FROM
(
    SELECT id, score
        , SUM(score) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY score DESC ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 1 FOLLOWING) AS best_score
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY score DESC) AS row_num
    FROM Scores
) AS t
INNER JOIN Members AS m ON (m.id = t.id AND t.row_num = 1) 
ORDER BY best_score DESC;
```

First, for each id the scores are ordered by descending.

```
(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY score DESC)
```

Then **SUM()** is used on the score of the current row and the following 1 row by the **ROWS** clause

```
ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 1 FOLLOWING
```

So the inner query returns the combined sum of 2 scores for each row. Then the first row number is used to get the best_score's row. **GROUP BY** could also be used instead.